# ReactJs How to expose lazy to outer component

Tags: reactjs

I have a folder of components and I'd like to dynamically determine what to display based on some config. I'm trying to use dynamic import with `lazy` and `Suspense`.

I managed to get this working:

```
function DynamicComponent({name, ...props}) {
  const ActualComponent = lazy(() => import(`./Components/${name}`));
  return <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}><ActualComponent {...props}/></Suspense>
}
```

However, I want to put `Suspense` on the outer component because I'd like to display a bunch of stuff together after loading is finished. I tried this:

```
function DynamicComponent({name, ...props}) {
  const ActualComponent = lazy(() => import(`./Components/${name}`));
  return <ActualComponent {...props}/>
}

function Container({...dynamicProps}) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div}>
      <div>Some other stuff</div>
      <DynamicComponent {...dynamicProps} /
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

However this will display `Loading` and will not change to the actual component. I suspect it's because I need to "expose" the loading status of `ActualComponent` from `DynamicComponent` so that `Suspense` in `Container` can pick it up. What's the right way to do it?